# Dynamically create plots in Chaco

Tags: python, plot, traits, enthought, chaco

The Chaco plotting toolkit for Python includes examples that show how to dynamically *update* existing plots. However, my application requires that I **dynamically create and destroy plots** depending on the data. I am new to programming with Chaco and Traits, so a simple example that illustrates how to do this would be really helpful.

Comment: Do you mean that you even don't want to see the plotting frame before you need the plot and to remove the plotting frame when it's time to be destroyed?

Comment: It's not so much that I don't _want_ to see the frame, it's that the data controls the number of plots and this number can change over time, so I can't create the frames ahead of time. Any thoughts on how one might go about doing this?

Comment: i'm sorry, don't have time for a nice answer right now. But the tutorials on this page really don't help you? http://github.enthought.com/chaco/user_manual/tutorial.html

Comment: @K.-Michael Aye : The link you provided is dead. Is this the right one : https://github.com/enthought/chaco/tree/master/examples/tutorials?

Comment: @K.-MichaelAye Today it is, 404.

Comment: http://docs.enthought.com/chaco/user_manual/tutorials_and_examples.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a bit late, but here's an example that creates and destroys Chaco plots. The main interface is `PlotSelector`, which defines some fake data and radio buttons to switch between two different plot styles (line and bar plots).

This example uses a Traits event to signal when to close a plot, and then handles that signal with `PlotController`. There may be a better way to close the window, but I couldn't find one.

**Edit**: Updated imports for newer versions of Traits, Chaco, and Enable (ETS 4 instead of 3).

```
import numpy as np

import traits.api as traits
import traitsui.api as ui
import chaco.api as chaco
from enable.api import ComponentEditor


class PlotController(ui.Controller):
    view = ui.View(ui.Item('plot', editor=ComponentEditor(), show_label=False),
                   height=300, width=300, resizable=True)

    def object_close_signal_changed(self, info):
        info.ui.dispose()


class BasicPlot(traits.HasTraits):
    close_signal = traits.Event()
    plot = traits.Instance(chaco.Plot)


class LinePlot(BasicPlot):

    def __init__(self, plotdata):
        self.plot = chaco.Plot(plotdata)
        self.plot.plot(('x', 'y'))


class BarPlot(BasicPlot):

    def __init__(self, plotdata):
        self.plot = chaco.Plot(plotdata)
        self.plot.candle_plot(('x', 'ymin', 'ymax'))


available_plot_types = dict(line=LinePlot, bar=BarPlot)

class PlotSelector(traits.HasTraits):

    plot_type = traits.Enum(['line', 'bar'])
    traits_view = ui.View('plot_type', style='custom')

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        ymin = y - 1
        ymax = y + 1
        self.plotdata = chaco.ArrayPlotData(x=x, y=y, ymin=ymin, ymax=ymax)
        self.figure = None

    def _plot_type_changed(self):
        plot_class = available_plot_types[self.plot_type]
        if self.figure is not None:
            self.figure.close_signal = True
        self.figure = plot_class(self.plotdata)
        controller = PlotController(model=self.figure)
        controller.edit_traits()


N = 20
x = np.arange(N)
y = x + np.random.normal(size=N)
plot_selector = PlotSelector(x, y)
plot_selector.configure_traits()
```

Note that the main interface (`PlotSelector`) calls `configure_traits` (starts application), while the plots are viewed with `edit_traits` (called from within application). Also, note that this example calls `edit_traits` from `PlotController` instead of calling it from the model. You could instead move the view from `PlotController` to `BasicPlot` and set the handler method of that view to `PlotController`.

Finally, if you don't need to totally destroy the plot window, then you may want to look at the `Plot` object's  `delplot` method, which destroys the **sub**plot (here the line plot or bar plot).

I hope that helps.